# Natively using WebRTC (or ORTC) on Windows 10 UWP

Tags: uwp, webrtc

Is there a way to create a WebRTC (or ORTC) client on Windows 10 for the UWP framework, without the need to rely on the WebView. I'd like to avoid JavaScript on the client side as much as possible.

Comment: As far as I understand you can make UWP apps in C++ so I guess it's possible to include the lib, but I don't know what restrictions Microsoft has put on UWP apps.

Comment: I think you should use win2d and unencod the html

Comment: @Kevin If that works at all, it will work for desktop only (unless there are both win32 and ARM libs). But I'm afraid this won't work since not all win32 API's are supported in UWP apps. But I'll look into it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: WebRTC is not available as a win32 lib though, just plain c++. You can build it yourself for various platforms, including iOS and Android (both ARM). So there's a chance it's possible to compile for UWP as well.

Comment: @Kevin I should have googled for that information, obviously. ;) Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way would be to use nuget:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebRTC/

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible with the Openpeer ORTC framework. There is a SDK that you can compile on GitHub [openpeer ORTC lib](https://github.com/openpeer/ortc-lib-sdk) that includes UWP samples. However I'm having a hard time getting the samples to work mostly due to crashing in the VS2015 Update 3 when loading the VS solutions from the SDK (command line compile works though).

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into it.

Comment: The OpenPeer ORTC framework is now built out and renamed ortclib https://github.com/ortclib